# Cannot get google sign in to work in flutter-web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

i thought it would work  after Flutter 1.9 but its still not working is there anyway to get the google_sign_in to work on flutter web? i couldn't find a thread for it or an article... thanks

I've setup the web application credentials in the console and added the required script at the top of the index.html file

Comment: What is your question. What you already tried?